# Angular setvalue to a form Control giving an error

Tags: angular

I am getting a user data from firebase. I want to place those data to my single form controls. When I am trying to place those in the form control it is giving me an error. I am using reactive forms for the form. How can I place those data in the single form field when component loads. Please find my code below.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.setDefault();
}


setDefault() {
    let contact = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      phonenumber: "",
      dob: "",
      address: "",
      state: "",
      city: "",
      pincode: "",
    };

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user.email);
        console.log(user.displayName);
        console.log(user.photoURL);
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("profiles")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (doc.data()) {
              console.log(doc.data().phonenumber);
              console.log(doc.data().dateofbirth);
              console.log(doc.data().fulladdress);
              console.log(doc.data().state);
              console.log(doc.data().city);
              console.log(doc.data().zipcode);
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
          });
      }
    });
    this.profileForm.setValue(contact);
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the error

Comment: When trying to put the value like name: user.displayName getting an red underline in the editor. How can i place the values in the contact object.

Comment: can you tell where you assign any value to contact

Comment: if I am assigning the value like this          name: user.displayName         then getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your trying to do is use your contact object to set your form values, 
if so your not setting your contact object (or missing line where you do).

```
let contact = {
  name: user.displayName,
  email: user.email,
  phonenumber: doc.data().phonenumber
  dob: doc.data().dateofbirth,
  address: doc.data().fulladdress,
  state: doc.data().state,
  city: doc.data().city,
  pincode: doc.data().zipcode,
};

this.profileForm.patchValue(contact);
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to to do this. But getting an error.

Comment: whats the error, are you sure the **user** object and **doc.data()** is correct?

Comment: No No There was a mistake and I rectified it. Now it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***You can use patchValue***

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            console.log(user.email);
            console.log(user.displayName);
            console.log(user.photoURL);
            firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("profiles")
              .doc(user.uid)
              .get()
              .then(doc => {
                if (doc.data()) {
                  console.log(doc.data().phonenumber);
                  console.log(doc.data().dateofbirth);
                  console.log(doc.data().fulladdress);
                  console.log(doc.data().state);
                  console.log(doc.data().city);
                  console.log(doc.data().zipcode);
                }
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error);
              });
          }
        });
        this.profileForm.patchValue(contact);
      }
```